# I want to use my DVD ROM in place of secondary HDD again in same SATA port

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

My Motherboard has only two SATA ports, recently  I added a New HDD and for that had to remove the DVD ROM. There are no new partitions and the whole new Drive initiated as 'H drive'.Now if I am going to use the DVD ROM again(by changing cables) and may later again have to add the HDD. Is it safe without any data loss?I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You may certainly turn off the computer and take out the disk, and nothing will
be lost. You only need to store the disk in good conditions, protected from
magnetic fields and extreme temperatures.

The disk will work fine the next time that it is installed again.

Just one remark: The fact that the disk is offline does not mean that some bits
might not deteriorate as time goes by.
It's not a safe storage media for many years.

Comment: I have connected hard drives stored in not so good environments for over 10 years and the data is still there and hash check just fine, ymmv. I guess there is no bullet proof storage medium for bits.

Comment: For modern Windows they might also need to run `shutdown /s /f` on an administrator command line in order to ensure that everything is properly unmounted without "fast startup" potentially holding on to disk state information.

Comment: @Mokubai: This is correct for the system drive, but it doesn't look like it's the case here.

Comment: State of other disks *may* be caught as well. Unless the drive is "optimised for quick removal" in device manager (i.e. a memory stick) then some state may be kept in RAM for any disk attached when hibernating the system. Hopefully not and if it does the NTFS journal should make it a moot point, but better safe than sorry.